# Difference between tenses?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

In the third paragraph of [this text](http://ieltsliz.com/ielts-advantage-disadvantage-model-essay/), there is a line

> Each culture is unique with its own way of life and perspectives of the world which would all be lost if there were only one language

If I replace "there were" with "there is" or "there was". Will it still be grammatically correct?

In the last paragraph of [this text](http://ieltsliz.com/ielts-model-essay-score-9/)

> If more people strived in life toward true happiness, the world would be a better place.

If I replace "the world would be a better place" with "the world would have been a better place" or "the world would had been a better place". Will it still be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

These sentences are examples of [hypothetical conditionals](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/conditionals-1), also known as second conditionals.

Rearranging your first sentence to lead with the if clause, this is what it looks like first as a simple conditional and then as a hypothetical coditional.

> If there **is** only one language, [it] **will** all be lost
>   If there **were** only one language, [it] **would** all be lost

A hpothetical conditional requires a subjunctive in both clauses. The only verb that has a distinct subjunctive is **be** where the subjunctive is **were**. For all other verbs, we simply [backshift](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) the tense, as we do for reported speech.

In informal spoken english, we can use a backshift instead of the subjunctive for **be**, so this sentence would be OK:

> If there **was** only one language, [it] **would** all be lost

To answer your first question, then, you cannot use **there is** because it breaks the pattern for a hypothetical conditional, but you can use **there was** in informal spoken english.

Rewriting your second example in simple and hypothetical conditionals:

> If more people **strive** in life toward true happiness, the world **will** be a better place.
>   If more people **strived** in life toward true happiness, the world **would** be a better place.

There is only one valid backshift for **will**, and it is **would**. The other options are not valid in this particular sentence.

The **would have** option would work if you were talking about a hypothetical past- what whould have happened if people had done different things in the past. Note that you have to change the verb in the first clause too.

> If more people **had strived** in life toward true happiness, the world **would have been** a better place.

THere is no sentence in which **would had been** is valid.

Comment: In this link - https://takeielts.britishcouncil.org/sites/default/files/Writing-practice_test_1_IELTS_General_Training_Model_Answers.pdf, in the last paragraph can I replace "there has been heavy rain" with "there was" or with "there is"?

Comment: That should really be a separete question.

Comment: Could you give me an answer, as I have an exam on 10th of Feb, please?